# Inquiry about an Instagram account

Tags: android

When I'm using my Instagram app it tells me that my feed couldn't refresh then shows me a page with the following:
{"message":"checkpoint_required", "checkpoint_url":"https://i.instagram.com/privacy/checks/?
privacy_flow=1\u0026next=instagram://checkpoint/dismiss":"lock":fals,"flow_render_type":0,"status":"fail"}

It does this repeatedly and more frequently the longer I'm using Instagram. Why is it doing this and how do I fix it?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwDV1.jpg)

Comment: Have the same problem today. Just needed to update the app from Play Store.